# Unable to execute PowerShell script from batch file to run in CMD mode

Tags: c#, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I created a PowerShell script for FileWatcher. I need to execute it in C#. I tried in many ways but it didn't work. I even created a batch file to execute my script. still it is not working, simply the console gets opened and closed. but when i run each step manually in the command prompt I could able to execute the script.

***Below is my PowerShell script:***

```cs
$folder = 'D:\'
$filter = '*.csv'
$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{
    IncludeSubdirectories = $false;
    NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'
}
Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Changed -SourceIdentifier FileChanged -Action {
    $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated
    Write-Host "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp" -Fore red
    Out-File -FilePath D:\outp.txt -Append -InputObject "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp"
}
```

***Here is the batch file***

```batch
D:
powershell.exe
powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
./FileWatcherScript
```

Comment: You say you need to run the PowerShell script from C#, but there is no C# code in your question.

Comment: Ansgar Wiechers, Thanks for your reply.
If my batch file works, then I can try in C# by my own.

Comment: Your batch file doesn't make any sense. The first `powershell.exe` starts PowerShell without returning, so no other command gets executed until you manually exit. Even then the 2nd command would just set the execution policy and return, while the last statement would try to execute a file `FileWatcherScript` with the first matching extension from `%PATHEXT%` from the current working directory. Since `.ps1` is not among these extensions that will simply raise an error that the command cannot be found. What you probably want to run is `powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File .\script.ps1`.

Answer (score 0):

To call a script from Powershell, you should use the `-File` argument. I'd change your batch file to look something like this - all you need is this one line:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File D:\FileWatcherScript.ps1
```

Starting `powershell.exe` without passing any arguments, as in the batch script in your post, will always start an interactive shell that must be exited manually. To run commands through Powershell programatically and exit when finished, you can pass the `-File` argument as I did above, or the `-Command` argument which takes a string or script block. Here is a short example of the `-Command` argument taking a string:

```
powershell.exe -Command "Invoke-RestMethod https://example.com/api/do/thing; Invoke-RestMethod https://example.com/api/stop/otherthing"
```

That invocation calls Invoke-RestMethod twice on two different URLs, and demonstrates that you can separate commands with a semicolon (`;`) to run one after another.

You can also pass a scriptblock to `-Command`, but note that this only works *from within another Powershell session*. That looks like this:

```
powershell.exe -Command { Invoke-RestMethod https://example.com/api/do/thing; Invoke-RestMethod https://example.com/api/stop/otherthing }
```

That invocation does the same thing as the previous one. The difference is that it is using a scriptblock - a Powershell construct, which again only works if the parent shell is also Powershell - and it's a bit nicer since you have fewer string quoting problems.